# Fix TextField Alignment in React

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I need to fix a simple problem in the styling of my React App. I wonder why the CVC TextField in my react app doesn't align to the Card Number.

Pls check this codesandbox link

[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-2w3jl?file=/demo.js)

```
<div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
  <TextField
    variant="outlined"
    label="Expiration Month"
    name="expiryMonth"
    type="text"
    value={values.expiryMonth}
    onChange={handleChange}
    onBlur={handleBlur}
    helperText={touched.expiryMonth ? errors.expiryMonth : ''}
    error={touched.expiryMonth && Boolean(errors.expiryMonth)}
    fullWidth
    className={classes.margin}
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
  />

  <TextField
    variant="outlined"
    label="Expiration Year"
    name="expiryYear"
    type="text"
    value={values.expiryYear}
    onChange={handleChange}
    onBlur={handleBlur}
    helperText={touched.expiryYear ? errors.expiryYear : ''}
    error={touched.expiryYear && Boolean(errors.expiryYear)}
    fullWidth
    className={classes.margin}
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
  />

  <TextField
    variant="outlined"
    label="CVC"
    name="cvc"
    type="number"
    value={values.cvc}
    onChange={handleChange}
    onBlur={handleBlur}
    helperText={touched.cvc ? errors.cvc : ''}
    error={touched.cvc && Boolean(errors.cvc)}
    fullWidth
    className={classes.margin}
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
  />
</div>;
```

Comment: Can you pls elaborate your question more? Only CVC field or others like expiry date field also to be full width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, each `TextField` has a margin of 8px due to which, the flex row of three text field(month, year and CVV) has 8 px gap with their children.

there are multiple fixes, the first one is

```
<div style={{ display: "flex", width="calc(100% + 16px)" }}>
```

This will force the row to take 16px more than 100% because we have 8px margin on TextField on both side so it will help us to overcome 8px margin on both side
another solution would be to add a negative margin of 16px on right side

```
<div style={{ display: "flex",  margin: "-16px" }}>
```

I would recommend you to use `Grid` component from MUI because it will also help you to achieve responsive design, below is the code with Grid as a container, to make it responsive you will need to wrap each child component TextField in `Grid` item component

```
<Grid
          style={{ display: "flex", margin: 0 }}
          container
          direction="row"
          justify="center"
          alignItems="center"
          spacing={2}
        >
```

[Sand-box-project-1](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-e06q6?file=/demo.js:7327-7523)

[Sand-box-project-2](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-6cciq?file=/demo.js:7356-7617)

Comment: Thanks. just use grid. Can you make sure if they are on mobile devices, the expiration month, expiration year and cvc will have their own row since it will be hard to write cause input is very small on mobile. Thanks

Comment: I have updated the [Second code box project](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-6cciq?file=/demo.js:7356-7617). Now all three textfield will be in a single row on desktop and in a separate row on mobile

Comment: Thanks. However, can you make the spacing in each TextField the same? The expiration year and CVC have a big gap on mobile screen. Pls make them uniform with the others. Thanks

Comment: I have made some changes, but in the end, you have to customize the styling by your own as per your need, and it is CSS only nothing major. I would highly recommend understanding the `styling` of MUI and learn how to customize/override the styles  it is a highly configurable UI library